# The meaning of the first line output in the iwconfig command in Linux

Tags: wireless-networking

When I'm using the iwconfig command on my current wifi interface , wlan0 , the first line I get as output  is `wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn`.
When I try to do this when I am connected to other WiFi's, I sometimes get other versions, like IEEE 802.11bg or IEEE 802.11abgn. I want to ask, what's the meaning of this output? if the output is IEEE 802.11bgn then it means that this WiFi supports both the b , g and n standards or it means something else?

Thnaks :)